# return an array of keys from hash when values match pattern

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, return, key

I am trying to run through the following hash

```
my_family_pets_ages = {"Evi" => 6, "Hoobie" => 3, "George" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4, "Annabelle" => 0, "Ditto" => 3}
```

and return an array of the keys whose values match a specified integer for age.  So, for example,  if I wanted to find all of the pets that are 3 years old, it would return an array of just their names.

```
["Hoobie", "Ditto"]
```

I have the following method, but I can't seem to get the method to return an array of just the keys, but I keep just getting the key => value in an array like this:

```
["Hoobie"=>3, "Ditto"=>3]
```

Here is the method I have so far

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select {|name, age| name if age == thing_to_find}
end
```

Any pointers? I'm stuck on how to return only the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), then [`#keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) to get an array of the matching keys:

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select { |name, age| age == thing_to_find }.keys
end
```

See [Hash#keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) for more information.

Comment: Please add an explanation of this . The OP is obviously new to ruby so an explanation will make your answer more useful to them as well as other users with the same question.

Comment: thanks so much!  I didn't know you could call the keys method on that entire block.  very helpful!

Comment: The block just returns a `Hash`, so you can call any `Hash` instance methods you'd like on it.